# Where to ask question on notebook configuration?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

I am about to buy a new notebook and would like to get some opinions on the configuration I have chosen. Is there a dedicated place to do this in the stack exchange network?

Comment: Sounds like you want opinions, and we deal in facts here. Perhaps a traditional discussion forum would be more suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, shopping questions are not allowed.

I would suggest, *in no particular order*, [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/), [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/), [Hot Hardware](http://hothardware.com/), (perhaps) [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/), or a site of similar ilk. I believe most of those have forums which are amenable to questions of this type.